# Define word boundaries

Tags: normal-mode, cursor-motions

I use, e.g., `dw` to delete a word based on word boundaries defined by changing character classes, so that this command applied on `abc,def,ghi` will result in `,def,ghi`. (So far so good, and it worked for me for decades.) Now, since just recently, that does not work any more on dots (`.`); that `dw` command applied on `abc.def;ghi` will result in `;ghi`.

Can anyone explain what happens here; maybe whether I changed some setting by accident. - How can that misbehaviour be fixed?

**Update:** Following Peter's hint in his answer I obtained:

```
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/sh.vim
```

and found this content in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/sh.vim`:

```
" AFAICT "." should be considered part of the iskeyword.  Using iskeywords in
" syntax is dicey, so the following code permits the user to prevent/override
" its setting.
if exists("g:sh_isk")          " override support
 exe "setlocal isk=".g:sh_isk
elseif !exists("g:sh_noisk")   " prevent modification support
 setlocal isk+=.
endif
```

Now this seems to be a system setting. I have no reservations against changing that file - only that it will be changed again on system updates, I fear. But since I am not familiar with vim's script language I'd be interested to know what the correct way to fix it would be. Personally I'd just remove the `.` so that the `+=` becomes a no-op, but I guess the whole `if` statement need to be fixed. (What's that `"g:sh_noisk"`?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like `'iskeyword'` changed recently. You can do `:verbose set iskeyword?` to see where `'iskeyword'` was last set.

Your specific issue is with the `sh` filetype. Here is an excerpt from `:h g:sh_isk`:

```
The shell languages appear to let "." be part of words, commands, etc;
consequently it should be in the isk for sh.vim.  As of v116 of syntax/sh.vim,
syntax/sh.vim will append the "." to 'iskeyword' by default; you may control
this behavior with:
    let g:sh_isk  = '..whatever characters you want as part of iskeyword'
    let g:sh_noisk= 1  " otherwise, if this exists, the isk will NOT chg
```

According to this you will need to add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
let g:sh_noisk = 1
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'iskeyword'
:h :set-verbose
:h local-options
:h g:sh_isk
:h ft-sh-syntax
```